# command line: replace newline followed by character

Tags: regex, perl, sed, command-line-interface, regexp-replace

I want to replace newlines `\n` in a file **only** when the next line starts with optional spaces and a lower than charachter `\s*<`.

*Example Text:*

```
FIRST LINE ('<foo>
  <bar>
<baz>')

ANOTHER LINE 'lorem ipsim', '<dolor>
        <and>
            <p>again</p>
        </and>
</dolor>'
```

I need to do that on the command line using sed, perl, tr, ...

I tried several command but none has worked so far.
Basically it is: `sed -i -e 's|\n+\s*\<|<|gm' filename`

It seems like sed does not look further than the newline.

https://regex101.com/r/VkRO9o/3

Is there any command that can do that?

EDIT: *Expected Output:*

```
FIRST LINE '<foo>  <bar><baz>'

ANOTHER LINE 'lorem ipsim', '<dolor><and><p>again</p></and><dolor>'
```

It's fine if the spaces aren't replaced.

Comment: @anubhava I added the expected output to the question.

There are many new lines in my file, but i only want to join the lines where a `<` is at the beginning (with optional spaces before that.

So the new line between *FIRST LINE* and *ANOTHER LINE* should remain.

Comment: It can be simple as `perl -0777 -pe "s/\n\s*(<)/$1/g" input.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `perl` for this:

```
perl -0777 -pe "s/\h*\R+\h*([<'])/\$1/g" file
```

```
FIRST LINE ('<foo><bar><baz>')

ANOTHER LINE 'lorem ipsim', '<dolor><and><p>again</p></and></dolor>'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VkRO9o/5)

**Details:**

- `-0777`: Enable slurp mode to match across newlines
- `/\h*\R+\h*([<'])`: Match 0+ horizontal whitespaces followed by 1+ line breaks followed by 0+ whitespaces and `<` or `'`. Note that we are capturing `<` or `'` in group #1. Replace this match with an `$1` which is `<` or `'` that we've captured in group #1